# How can I copy multiple files in the same directory with different names but same extension in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The requirement is to make copies of n(n>10000) files in the same linux directory.
The extension of the files has to be intact and can probably add numbers to distinguish among files.

For e.g. if one file is text1.txt the other could be text2.txt

But I have to create multiple copies from multiple files and not from a single file.

Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash pattern substitution might help you here. If you e.g. want to copy all .txt files, you can do it like this:

```sh
for file in *.txt # add any other name wildcards
do
    filename=${file%.*} # removes everything after the last dot
    extension=${file##*.} # removes everything before the last dot
    cp "$file" "${filename}-copy.${extension}" # adds the -copy suffix to every copy
done
```

Comment: Please don't [parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and *do* [quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) properly.

Comment: Thanks Tobias.
Make sure there is no space between "filename" and "=" same with extension. seems to be a typo.

Comment: @l0b0 Thanks for the reminder, I'm too much used to filenames not containing spaces!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into tools like [logrotate](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/understanding-logrotate-utility/) which can take for example a glob and rotate each of the files on a regular basis.